# Weird results using strptime to transform items in a list

Tags: python, datetime, transformation, strptime

I'm trying to convert the second and third element in a Python list from strings into time format. I'm using the strptime method in Python 3.5.1.

When I run the transformation and print the new "clean_times" list, I get a weird set of results: "datetime.time(13, 25, 16, 555550)" repeated four times instead of the two time values I would expect.

```
>>> string_times = ["somefile.txt", "8:02:31.12", "8:31:12.34"]
>>> print (string_times)
['somefile.txt', '8:02:31.12', '8:31:12.34']
>>> for each_time in string_times[1:2]:
    clean_times.append(datetime.strptime(each_time, '%H:%M:%S.%f').time())
>>> print (clean_times)
[datetime.time(13, 25, 16, 555550), datetime.time(13, 25, 16, 555550), datetime.time(13, 25, 16, 555550), datetime.time(8, 2, 31, 120000)]
```

Anybody seen this before?

Comment: string_times[1:2] returns only the 2nd elem.

Comment: my result is `[datetime.time(8, 2, 31, 120000)]`. are you sure that you're executing that code?

Comment: I bet you ran this code four times in the python REPL and just forgot to clear or reinitialize the `clean_times` array/variable ;)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Restarting the shell did the trick.

Comment: Thanks also for the comment about how [1:2] will only return the second value.